# countifs criteria range is more than vba

Tags: vba, excel

This is simple, it works when i type the function into excel, but not when i run it through VBA

what am i missing from this VBA?
It has 3 criteria ranges and criterias

the first 2 criteria are for a date range (more than 10th less than 15th, for example)
the 3rd criteria is to count the number of entries in that date range for a value

When i run the function within excel, i get the correct answer of 400, but i get 0 when run through VBA?

```
.Cells(9, 4).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F8:F1000000"), " >= " & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D10"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F8:F1000000"), " <= " & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H10"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D8:D1000000"), "TestSearch")
```

Will appreciate any guidance, thank you :)

Comment: Can you provide any example data?

Comment: Having done a quick test, it seems to because of the spaces inside the quotes.

Comment: which spaces exactly @SJR ?

Comment: try to erase the spaces from these two quotes as SJR wrote: " <= " and " >= "

Comment: Try to use `.Cells(9, 4).value` instead of `.Cells(9, 4).Formula`, because usually `.Cells(9, 4).Formula = "=countifs(...)"`

Comment: unfortunately, removing the spaces in quotes made no difference, and changing to ".value" also made not difference

Comment: Can you provide the excel formula that works?

Comment: Are your dates in US format?

Comment: @Aneta '=COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!F:F,">="&'Sheet2'!D10,'Sheet1'!F:F,"<="&'Sheet2'!H10,'Sheet1'!D:D,"TestSearch")'

Comment: @EvR All in same UK format for both criteria range and the criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned UK dates instead of US dates (VBA) so try to convert your criteria dates to long:

```
" >= " & clng(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D10")), ....
```

Comment: perfect! could you please explain the semantics and why this works please